# How to avoid deletion of object given as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, parameter-passing

I am new to C++ and I do not know how to solve the following problem.

The class Foo has a constructor which creates a array of doubles of a given size. The destructor deletes this array. The print method prints the array.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
private:
    int size;
    double* d;
public:
    Foo(int size);
    ~Foo();
    void print();
};

Foo::Foo(int size)
{
    this->size = size;
    d = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        d[i] = size * i;
    }
}
Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete[] d;
}
void Foo::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << d[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Now I have a function `func(Foo f)` which does nothing.

```
void func(Foo f){}

int main()
{
    Foo f(3);
    f.print();
    func(f); 
    Foo g(5);
    f.print();

    return 0;    
}
```

Executing this code gives the following output:

```
0  3  6
0  5  10
```

Although I am printing `f` both times, somehow the values inside the array have changed.

I guess that the destructor of Foo is called on parameter `Foo f` after the execution of `func(Foo f)` and this frees the allocated memory for `d`, which is reallocated for `Foo g(5)`. But how can I avoid this without using vectors or smart pointers?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `std::vector<double>` instead of an array.  The `std::vector` will manage dynamic memory for you (and it's been tested).

Comment: Use references.

Comment: You can remove the `this->` notation by choosing different names for parameters and members.

Comment: You're violating the Rule of Three.

Comment: it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the design of the class.  The default copy constructor will create a new instance of `Foo` when passed by **value** into the free standing function named `func`.

When the instance of `Foo` named `f` exits scope then the code invokes the user-provided destructor that deletes the array of doubles.  This opens the code to the unfortunate situation of deleting the same array twice when the original instance of `Foo` named `f` exits scope at the end of the program.

When run on my machine, the code does not produce the same output.  Instead I see two output lines of `0 3 6` followed by fault indicating the double free operation.

The solution is to avoid the copy by passing by reference (or by const reference): `void func(Foo const &f) { }` or to supply a valid copy constructor that makes a deep copy of the underlying array.  Passing by reference is just a bandaid that avoids exercising the bug.

Using `std::vector<double>` fixes the problem because the default copy constructor will perform a deep copy and avoid double deallocation.  This is absolutely the best approach in this small example, but it avoids having to understand the root of the problem.  Most C++ developers will learn these techniques then promptly do what they can to avoid having to write code that manually allocates and deallocates memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably pass the object as a reference `func(Foo& f)` or - if you do not want to modify it at all - as a constant reference `func(const Foo& f)`. This will not create or delete any objects during the function call.

Aside from that, as others have already mentioned, your class should better implement the Rule of Three.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a value to a function, it is supposed to be copied. The destructor is run on the copy and should no effect on the original object. `Foo` fails to implement a copy constructor, so compiler provides the default one which simply performs a member-wise copy of the struct. As a result, the "copy" of `Foo` inside `Func` contains the same pointer as the original, and its destructor frees the data pointed to by both.

In order to be usable by idiomatic C++ code, `Foo` **must** implement at least a copy constructor and an assignment operator in addition to the destructor. The rule that these three come together is sometimes referred to as "the rule of three", and is mentioned in other answers.

Here is an (untested) example of what the constructors could look like:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& other) {
    // copy constructor: construct Foo given another Foo
    size = other->size;
    d = new double[size];
    std::copy(other->d, other->d + size, d);
}

Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo& other) {
    // assignment: reinitialize Foo with another Foo
    if (this != &other) {
        delete d;
        size = other->size;
        d = new double[size];
        std::copy(other->d, other->d + size, d);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Additionally, you can also modify functions like `func` to accept a reference to `Foo` or a constant reference to `Foo` to avoid unnecessary copying. Doing this alone would also happen fix the immediate problem you are having, but it would not help other issues, so you should definitely implement a proper copy constructor before doing anything else.

It's a good idea to get a good book on C++ where the rule of three and other C++ pitfalls are explained. Also, look into using STL containers such as `std::vector` as members. Since they implement the rule of three themselves, your class wouldn't need to.

Comment: The code shown in the answer is an assignment operator.  The code in the original question has an instance of Foo passed by value, which invokes the copy constructor.

Comment: @Ben The answer shows *both* a copy constructor and an assignment operator (and says so), because omiting the assignment operator would lead to a similar bug the first time someone assigned to a `Foo`.

Answer (score -2):

One problem is that calling func creates a bitwise copy. When that copy goes out of scope the destructor is called which deletes your array. 
You should change void func(Foo f){} to void func(Foo& f){}.
But better yet you add a create copy constructor or add a private declaration to stop it being called unexpectedly.

Comment: It's a **memberwise** copy, not a **bitwise** copy. With a raw pointer there's no difference, and, as this answer says, that's the problem. With a shared pointer, on the other hand, the compiler-generated copy constructor would call the shared pointer's copy constructor, which would fix the problem.

Comment: Surely there's a difference because in a memberwise rather than a tailored copy constructor >1 object can share the same data. No?